# Please give me an anti-spam mail measure recipe

Tags: spam, procmail

How can I configure Procmail and SpamAssassin to catch spam?

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly?  If I translate this, you want people to give you examples of spam that will get through a spam filter and/or cause said filter to develop false positives, score skewing, or other undesirable phenomena?

Comment: I think he's just asking how to configure them to catch spam.

Comment: No!!! Sorry I'm not native english speaker.
I wanna delete all spam mail with procmail.

Comment: Yes how to configure them to catch spam.

Answer (score 2):

```
#spam assain
:0fw
| spamassassin 2>> ~/logs/spam_log
:0:
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
     .spam/
```

Is the bit of my .procmailrc that actually catches spam. My spam assassin user_prefs then looks something like this.

```
ok_locales en
use_bayes 1
bayes_min_ham_num 100
bayes_min_spam_num 100
bayes_ignore_header X-Bogosity
bayes_ignore_header X-Spam-Flag
bayes_ignore_header X-Spam-Status
```

You'll probably want to toggle ok_locales for where you live, and this relies heavily on bayesian filtering, so you'll need to feed your filters regularly with something along the lines of

```
 sa-learn --showdots --spam --file ~/Maildir/.spam/cur
 sa-learn --showdots --spam --file ~/Maildir/.inbox/cur
```